# Need a pattern or solution for a long running work that gets execute in a loop and updates the UI after each thread is finished

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I have a basic scenario where I need to complete a list of tasks where the UI is updated after each task and the tasks must be performed in order.

I have a WPF application that needs to process n requests to a specified database and after each task i need to update the application with the results of the task.

```
foreach(var task in tasks)
{
   // create thread for task to hit a database
   // update ui with result from the task
}
```

If I do this without threading the UI doesn't update until all tasks are finished and the application freezes until each task is finished.

The UI will add a row to a datagrid showing the results of each "task" that executed on a database.

Thanks,

-bmm

Answer (score 2):

[`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) with progress reporting will do exactly this. You can include whatever you need in the `UserState` property and apply it in your `ProgressChanged` event handler.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the new `Task` class that has the handy method `ContinueWith`, that allows you to queue up more work once the current task is finished. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx.

Thus, you can implement a flow like:

1. instantiate task with initial action
2. continue with update of GUI
3. continue with next task
4. go back to step 2

Answer (score 0):

You can also use ThreadPool

Here is an example.

```
      ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate
        {

            //Do something

            //Update ui.
            TextBox.Dispather.Invoke((Action)(() =>
            {
                //Update the control
            }));

        });
```